# Must a ring (commutative, with 1), in which every non-zero ideal is prime, be a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

An early exercise in Irving Kaplansky's *commutative rings* asks:

**Let R be a ring. Suppose that every ideal in R (other than R) is prime. Prove that R is a field.**

This is easy if we assume the zero ideal is prime. But is this assumption necessary?

If every non-zero ideal is prime, then for any non-unit $x \in R$ and with $x^{n+1} \ne 0$ we must have $\langle x \rangle \subseteq \langle x^{n+1} \rangle$, which requires the existence of an element $y$ satisfying:
$$
x(1-x^ny) = 0
$$
The collection of these and similar relations on the elements seems rather restrictive, but I would appreciate a simple and incisive argument to show that the condition that all non-zero ideals are prime can only be met by rings with trivial spectrum, or, if my guess is incorrect and this is untrue, a counter-example.

Comment: Note that Kaplansky's original statement is not quite right, since you also have to require that $R$ is nonzero.  (If $R$ is the zero ring, then there are no ideals other than $R$ so the condition is vacuously true.)

Comment: @EricWofsey: I think your point is that fields are usually required to have $1 \neq 0$, hence (somewhat unusually by comparison with groups and rings and modules and ...) the trivial structure with just one element isn't a field. If Kaplansky allows $1 = 0$ in a field as some authors do, then his statement is right.

Comment: I have never seen any author that allows $1=0$ in a field.

Comment: I agree that it is usual to require $1 \neq 0$, but Weber's original definition allowed it: he says explicitly that $0$ is distinct from $1$ except in the uninteresting case when the field has only one  element. See https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0043?tify page 527. (Please forgive me for going back to the 19th century, but I've become a fan of going back to original sources in mathematics recently.)

Comment: ... and in modern definitions the requirement that $1 \neq 0$ is often sneaked in surreptitiously by saying that that then non-zero elements of the field form a group under multiplication (which implies there is at leat one non-zero element, because the traditional definition of a group requires a group to have a non-empty universe).

Comment: I have found a more modern reference that doesn't require $1 \neq 0$: namely David Marker's *Model theory: an introduction*, Example 1.2.8 on p. 17. You can see it in the limited preview [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3LIPBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). I should stress that I am not a fan of the weaker definition: it makes talking about things like maximal ideals harder.

Comment: Marker's definition is a mistake, not an intentional inclusion of the zero ring.  If you read on, he never addresses the possibility that the zero ring is allowed and states many theorems that are wrong if it is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, let $R=K\times L$ where $K$ and $L$ are fields.  Then the only nonzero proper ideals in $R$ are $K\times 0$ and $0\times L$, which are both prime, but $R$ is not a field.

For another example, consider $R=\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$ for any prime $p$.  The only nonzero proper ideal is $(p)$ which is prime.

Here is a classification of all the examples.  Suppose $R$ is a ring in which every nonzero proper ideal is prime.  For any prime $P\subseteq R$, then $R/P$ has the same property but is a domain, and so must be a field.  Thus in fact every nonzero proper ideal is maximal.

If $R$ has two different nonzero proper ideals $P$ and $Q$, then we must have $P\cap Q=0$ (since the intersection is a non-maximal proper ideal).  By the Chinese remainder theorem we then get an isomorphism $R\cong R/P\times R/Q$ and so $R$ is a product of two fields.

If $R$ has exactly one nonzero proper ideal $P$, then $P$ is the nilradical of $R$ (since it is the unique prime ideal) and is principal (generated by any of its nonzero elements).  This implies $P^2=0$ (otherwise it would be a smaller nonzero proper ideal) and that $P\cong R/P$ as an $R$-module (otherwise $P$ would be an $R/P$-vector space of dimension greater than $1$ and so would have a nontrivial proper subspace).  If the quotient map $R\to R/P$ has a section which is a ring-homomorphism, then we can identify $R$ with $K[x]/(x^2)$ where $K$ is the field $R/P$.  But such a section may not exist, as shown by the example $R=\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$ above.

Finally, if $R$ has no nonzero proper ideals, it is either a field or the zero ring.

All of these cases can be joined together into the following equivalent characterization: $R$ is a ring in which every nonzero proper ideal is prime iff $R$ is an artinian ring of length at most $2$ as a module over itself.